# Why can't I get any output from my recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to insert the characters (a, b, c) and get the permutation of the array.

For some reason its not printing out. I'm sure its a simple mistake but I can't find it. Much appreciative for the advice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] A = new int []{'a','b','c'};
    permute(A, 3);
}

public static void permute(int[] A, int p){
    if(A.length == 0){
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        char ch = (char) p;
        p += A[i];
        permute(A,p);
        p = ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually don't have any method to print results out. Shouldn't you have something like `System.out.println()` somewhere?

Comment: It gives to you an error? Or an unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Well you never instruct the java program to print something? Do you expect this to happen out of the blue?

Comment: What does `p` represents?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your approach:

- You use `char`s when you should use `int`s and vice versa;
- The program doesn't contain any `System.out.print` statements, so you never instruct the Java program to print anything;
- This isn't a program that enumerates over all possible permutations. This will in fact generate a *stack overflow exception* (not to be confused with the name of this site), simply because the length of the array never changes, thus you always will call the `for` part and keep building up a call stack; and
- It is unclear what `p` means.

An *in-line* permutation program looks like:

```
public static void permute(char[] a, int p){
    if(p >= a.length) {//we've reached the end of the array, now print
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        char cp = a[p];
        for(int i = p; i < a.length; i++){
            char ci = a[i];
            a[p] = ci;
            a[i] = cp;
            permute(a,p+1);
            a[i] = ci;
        }
        a[p] = cp;
    }
}
```

[**online jDoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/p7).

Then you call the method with `permute(a,0)` with `a` the list of characters you wish to permutate.

Comment: My apologies, p represents the index of the first item. And yes I would need to add System.out.println() to produce an output which I did. I didn't mean to take that out. That was my mistake. I did get an stackoverflow error which was caused by permute(A, p); . Thank you all for the help. CommuSoft I will try this out.